# Transform this cURL instructions to PHP cURL commands

Tags: php, curl

I'am tiring to post into a API one img file. I am getting error again an again.
The suggested code for cURL is

```
curl -X POST --include 'https://eyeris-emovu1.p.mashape.com/api/image/' \
  -H 'X-Mashape-Key: ecxplgnAZ3mshB7MJtF0LAuSLU1fp1fjw1ujsnH07YUjXVWgea' \
  -H 'LicenseKey: <required>' \
  -F 'imageFile=@<file goes here>'
```

I am using this code:

```
$ch = curl_init('https://eyeris-emovu1.p.mashape.com/api/image/');

$cfile = curl_file_create('yo.jpg','image/jpeg','test_name');

$data = array('imageFile' => $cfile);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT'); // -X
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, TRUE); // --data-binary
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Content-Type: image/jpg', 'X-Mashape-Key: <myMashapeKey>', 'LicenseKey: <myEyerisKey>']); // -H

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

$request= curl_exec($ch);
print $request;
curl_close($ch);
```

But I don't get any answer.
The Keys are fine, because if I don't send a img I get a json with the response.
I checked and I have cURL enable and my PHP version is 5.6.11

Could please someone help me?

Thanks

Comment: In the CLI Curl POST is used; you use PUT in your php code.

Comment: Hi Sander, I change that but this not a solution. I continues with nothing.

Comment: Also I found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25032517/php-curl-setopt-equivalent-to-curl-d/32183202#32183202

Comment: So what exactly is your output? Are there errors in your error_log? Which PHP version are you running?